# HTML (table) elements with dynamic controls?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

So I don't get something that looks like this

[image]

I could use multiple placeholders to achieve this but I feel as though that is inefficient and would take longer to loop through each control. It would also cause problems with the "remove" button because the remove will only associate itself with the placeholder it is currently in. I want everything to display like the first row of controls which are separated with table cells.

Comment: You can use css or table to achieve what you want

Comment: I'm not trying to be cynical, but the problem is that you're trying to use the `<table>`. Just display the controls and leverage something like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: I was thinking that. So I create a class for the place holder and then what? I only know basic css.

Answer (score 0):

You have different ways:
1. Use only one row to add or edit a record and use a gridview or repeater to show data
2. use gridview in editmode (but i'm not expert about this)
3. you can put controls in gridview or repeater and manage all events using item/rowcommand